# blue warning suppression, zip folder

Tags: vimrc, vimscript

Is there a way I can remove the blue warnings that appear when editing a file from a zip folder in vim? Is there some setting I can apply in the vimrc file?

[image]

Sorry, they are not really warnings but info about the location of the particular file in the zip folder

Comment: Please provide more detail. It's a bit vague when you say "editing a file from a zip folder". And a screenshot of the warnings would be a good thing, too.

Comment: FYI I can "edit" a zip file and from there "edit" the files within without any issues or warnings. That's why I've requested the additional details.

Comment: Christian, this is the status line of the window displaying the file. When a file from a zip is opened, it is opened in a split window. The long name you see is a artificial name build from the name of the zip and the name of the zip entry. So Vim is displaying two windows. The upper window is the file from the zip. The lower window contains the zip listing. The window with the zip listing only has a height of 1 line to maximize the room for the file you want to edit.

Comment: You are right! I notice i can switch files also using the ctrl-w command

Comment: @Ralf sounds like a start on a good answer?

Comment: I think "close" is the better option since the question (how to suppress warnings?) is based on a misunderstanding (those aren't warnings).

Comment: @Christian : Ralf try to say "it is NOT A WARNING, it is only the normal behavior of vim, to display the circumstance 'you are see the contents of a file inside a zip-archive'" and "no, you can not change this behavior".